# Iterating through Observable list in RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm uploading some photos to a cloud service with RxJava. I'm limited to the cloud service's API, so I can get a Flowable object for each photo I want to upload.

I am using a zip operator to combine all the objects (I'm casting the Flowables into Obseravles). this is my code:

```
private void startUpload(ArrayList<InCartProductModel> printableProducts) {
        // Create a list of Observables
        List<Observable<Progress<FileLink>>> observables = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < printableProducts.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList<SelectablePhoto> productPhotos = printableProducts.get(i).getSelectablePhotos();

            for (int j = 0; j < productPhotos.size(); j++) {
                observables.add(getObservable(productPhotos.get(j)));
            }
        }

        Observable<PhotosZipObject> observable = Observable.zip(observables, args -> {
            PhotosZipObject zipObject = new PhotosZipObject();
            zipObject.results = args;
            return zipObject;
        });

        ArrayList<FileLink> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        observable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(zipObject -> {
                    List<FileLink> data = (List<FileLink>) (Object) Arrays.asList(zipObject.results);
                    arrayList.addAll(data);
                    uploadDialog.dismiss();
                }, throwable -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "הייתה בעיה בטעינת הנתונים. אנא נסה שנית", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("SplashScreenActivity", "error while posting order: " + throwable);
                    uploadDialog.dismiss();
                });

    }


    class PhotosZipObject {
        Object[] results;
    }
```

For some reason, my method doesn't work if there are more then 24 photos (Application crashes)

Is there any other way to achieve the same result?

Thanks

Comment: What's the Stackrace?

Comment: @Fred Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 68559200 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 56MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 167497024, growth limit 201326592"

Comment: This is a bit a shot in the dark, but maybe you're uploading too many photos at the same time. Can you try using the computation scheduler instead of the io? The computation scheduler has a limit of threads (only as many as the cores present in the device). Maybe this will limit the ammount of things in memory. The upload will be slower though.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the problem. I was trying to handle this manually and split the whole thing into pieces, but I faced another error... I would like to try your method and I'll update